# Trying to create a notifications badge in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a notifications badge and a panel of links in Angular. I am pretty close but I have run into two issues. The first being that I want to change the class from "activeLink" to "visitedLink" not toggle the classes with ng-click. The second is I only want to return the items that are classed as activeLinks in the badge.

https://jsfiddle.net/mvk0851x/9/

Markup

```
<div ng-app='deliverablesApp'>
  <div class="notes" ng-controller="NoteCtrl">NOTIFICATIONS <span class="badge">{{noteCount.length}}</span>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="note in noteCount | limitTo: 4" >
        <a ng-click="changeLink = !changeLink" 
           ng-class="{'activeLink': !changeLink, 'visitedLink': changeLink}"
           href="#"
           >
          {{note.update}}
        </a>
        <br />
        <cite>{{note.date | date: 'medium'}}</cite>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('deliverablesApp', [])
    app.controller('NoteCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.noteCount = [
        {
            update:"Sample text for Note 1",
            link:"note-update-link",
            date: 1441133965418 
        },
        {
            update:"Sample text for Note 2",
            link:"note-update-link",
            date: 1441129965418
        },
        {
            update:"Sample text for Note 3",
            link:"note-update-link",
            date: 1440629965418
        },
        {
            update: "Sample text for Note 4",
            link:"note-update-link",
            date: 1440622965418
        },
        {
            update: "Sample text for Note 5",
            link:"note-update-link",
            date: 1440621765418
        }];
  });
})();
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent class change in all the items when clicking on one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have more control on your application state you should store it in your model — not class list.

As I understood there are two problems here:

1. Click on one of the items triggers all items to change className.
2. There is wrong number of notifications shown in the first line.

To solve both you should place data to your model. For example:

```
$scope.notes = [
    {
        update:"Sample text for Note 1",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1441133965418,
        visited: false
    },
    {
        update:"Sample text for Note 2",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1441129965418,
        visited: false
    },
    {
        update:"Sample text for Note 3",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1440629965418,
        visited: false
    },
    {
        update: "Sample text for Note 4",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1440622965418,
        visited: false
    },
    {
        update: "Sample text for Note 5",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1440621765418,
        visited: false
    }
];
```

Do you see `visited: false` in each item of collection.
Now you are able to

1. Track visited items independently
2. Filter visited items

So now your template should be as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="note in notes" >
  <a
    ng-click="note.visited = true"
    ng-class="{'activeLink': !note.visited, 'visitedLink': note.visited}"
    href="#">
      {{note.update}}
  </a>
  <br />
  <cite>{{note.date | date: 'medium'}}</cite>
</li>
```

And if you want to get only not yet visited items, you should filter them out:

```
var visitedNotes = $scope.notes.filter(function (item) {
    return !item.visited;
});
```

The next step would be to create `Note` class to encapsulate this logic in it. For example (ES6)

```
class Note {
  constructor(params) {
    Object.assign(this, params);
    this.visited = false;
  }

  visit() {
    this.visited = true;
  }
}


...

$scope.notes = [
    {
        update:"Sample text for Note 1",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1441133965418 
    },
    {
        update:"Sample text for Note 2",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1441129965418
    },
    {
        update:"Sample text for Note 3",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1440629965418
    },
    {
        update: "Sample text for Note 4",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1440622965418
    },
    {
        update: "Sample text for Note 5",
        link:"note-update-link",
        date: 1440621765418
    }].map(function (data) {
      return new Note(data);
    });

...

<a ng-click="note.visit()">
```